# Why do USB ports cease to work?

Tags: usb, port, energy

I had an e-reader plugged into one of the 3 USB ports of my laptop. Later I realized it wasn't charging up anymore. I switched ports and the issue was gone. Why do USB ports stop working suddenly?

Comment: This is not a terrible question, but in the current form it is hard to answer because you are not specific enough. Try including information such as laptop (main board) brand, operating system and any steps necessary to reproduce the erratic behavior on your setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be for many reasons. Among them:

- Outdate drivers
- Bad USB port
- Bad USB cable
- Sleep / lower power state entered and not exited
- Failing Printer
- Dirty registry (Stay away from cleaners)